# Unusual connections of numbers

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, number-theory

Let's have the equation $(DX)^2-Y^2= ± Z^5$ and $x,y$ two positive integers greater than zero. From some facts we can obtain solutions of the above equation by giving integer values at $x,y$. Examples:

- if $x=11$ and $y=2$ then we have the solution $11*(641)^2-(2122)^2=7^5$;
- if $x=5$  and $y=2$ then we have the solution $5*(305)^2-(682)^2=1^5$;
- if $x=7$  and $y=4$ then we have the solution $7*(2449)^2-(6484)^2=(-9)^5$.

The puzzle is:

1. Can you present more such solutions?
2. What is the trick to solving such equations?

Comment: I think you mean $DX^2$ not $(DX)^2$, right? This would be consistent with the solutions you present. (Great puzzle btw!)

Comment: I meant $ (DX)^2$.

Comment: But with $(DX)^2$ your proposed solutions are not solutions, since they involve "something times a square, minus a square, equals a fifth power" and not "a square minus a square equals a fifth power".

Comment: $(DX)^2-Y^2= ± Z^5$ is the correct expression.

Comment: Then can you explain how $11*(641)^2-(2122)^2=7^5$ is a solution of the expression $(DX)^2-Y^2=\pm Z^5$? It seems rather to be a solution of the expression $DX^2-Y^2=\pm Z^5$.

Comment: When I reveal what $DX$ is equal to, then you will have your explanation.

Comment: $DX=√x*(x^2+10xy^2+5y^4)$ Given this information you can solve $(DX)^2 -Y^2 = ± Z^5$.

Comment: But wouldn't it make a lot more sense to write $DX^2-Y^2=Z^5$? Then the numbers $D,X,Y,Z$ are all integers, and the equation looks like the one that you've solved in your examples rather than just "difference of two squares".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The calculation process

Given $x$ and $y$, calculate

> $x-y^2=Z$,

so that

> $(y-\sqrt{x})(y+\sqrt{x})=-Z$.

Taking powers, this means

> $(y-\sqrt{x})^5(y+\sqrt{x})^5=-Z^5$.

Now we know that

> $(y+\sqrt{x})^5$ is a number in the form $Y+X\sqrt{x}$ for some integers $X,Y$, and then by conjugation $(y-\sqrt{x})^5=Y-X\sqrt{x}$.

So we have found a solution

> $(Y-X\sqrt{x})(Y+X\sqrt{x})=-Z^5$,

or in other words $DX^2-Y^2=Z^5$ with

> $D=x$, $X=5y^4+10xy^2+x^2$, $Y=y^5+10xy^3+5x^2y$,

or in the OP's notation $(DX)^2-Y^2=Z^5$ with

> $D=\sqrt{x}$, $X=5y^4+10xy^2+x^2$, $Y=y^5+10xy^3+5x^2y$.

### An example

Let's start with the relatively simple example $x=2,y=1$ and calculate as follows:

- > $Z=1$, $(1-\sqrt{2})(1+\sqrt{2})=-1$,
- > $(1+\sqrt{2})^5=1+5(\sqrt{2})+10(2)+10(2\sqrt{2})+5(4)+(4\sqrt{2})=41+29\sqrt{2}$,
- > $(41-29\sqrt{2})(41+29\sqrt{2})=(-1)^5$,

and the solution $2*(29)^2-(41)^2=1^5$, which can be checked by calculator.

As another example with an even value of $Z$, let's use $x=3,y=1$ and get:

- > $Z=2$, $(1-\sqrt{3})(1+\sqrt{3})=-2$,
- > $(1+\sqrt{3})^5=1+5(\sqrt{3})+10(3)+10(3\sqrt{3})+5(9)+(9\sqrt{3})=76+44\sqrt{3}$,
- > $(76-44\sqrt{3})(76+44\sqrt{3})=(-2)^5$,

and the solution $3*(44)^2-(76)^2=2^5$, which can be checked by calculator.

### My thought process

This whole puzzle seems likely to be something to do with

> [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) and the associated theory of algebraic number fields,

indeed the second of the examples given in the OP is actually a solution of this equation. The new feature in this puzzle, compared with the stuff I learned in undergraduate number theory courses, is the involvement of fifth powers. How can we relate fifth powers to

> the square-root arithmetic that enables solutions of Pell's equation? Well, if we have $a-b\sqrt{d}$ giving rise to an integer $n$ when multiplied by its conjugate, then $(a-b\sqrt{d})^5$ will similarly give rise to the integer $n^5$.

I then spotted the pattern in the given values that

> $11-2^2=7$, $5-2^2=1$, $7-4^2=-9$,

which confirmed for me the direction in which to approach this puzzle.

Comment: Can you present a couple of numerical examples with your thought process?

Comment: @Vassilis Sure, done.

Comment: You did a good job Rand. FYI $Y= y^5 + 10xy^3 +  5x^2y$. Now you can find what $DX$ is equal to.

Comment: @Vassilis $X=5y^4+10xy^2+x^2$ and $D=\sqrt{x}$?

Comment: You are very close.Give it another try and then I will reveal the answer.